# Jacoco Code coverage in IntelliJ for Remote Run/Debug Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, code-coverage, jacoco

We're using IntelliJ version 14 and are trying to add Jacoco code coverage to our remote Java application project. This is defined under the "Remote" option in the Edit Run/Debug Configuration.
Is there any way to activate Code Coverage for Remote app? There is no "Coverage" tab.
This is not a standard app with a main method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enabling code coverage requires adding a JVM agent that instruments bytecode to collect coverage information. When you use the Remote configuration, the JVM is not started by IntelliJ IDEA, and therefore there is no way to enable code coverage through the IntelliJ IDEA UI.

You can enable the coverage manually by modifying the VM options used to start your remote process and adding the coverage agent.